# Can I use the same method with different but comparable inputs?

Tags: java, methods

I am writing the following method, which takes an array as input and writes the elements of this array to a .txt file:

```
public static void writeArrayToTxt(Object[] array, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filename, "UTF-8");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            String line = "";                       
            line = array[i] + "";                   
            writer.println(line);
        }
        writer.close();
    }
```

However, I would like to be able to use the same method for both an array of integers and an array of doubles, as this does not require a different method body. Is this possible? If so, what input should I give to the method?

Just trying

```
int[] arrayInt = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
writeArrayToTxt(arrayInt, "test.txt");
```

will give 'The method writeArrayToTxt(Object[], String) in the type test is not applicable for the arguments (int[], String)'

Comment: Use method overloads when possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, `int` is premitive data type in java and can't be represent it as an `Object`. Use `Integer` :

```
 Integer[] arrayInt = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Note: if you only want to pass `Integer`  and `Double` array I will suggest using a more specific argument like Number[] array:

```
writeArrayToTxt(Number[] array, String filename)
```

If you get int[] as a return of any method then you can convert it to Integer[] / Double[] like below.

```
int[] arrayInt = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Integer[] arrayInteger = Arrays.stream(arrayInt).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: Thank you, but my method will be used for output from other classes, which will all return int[] or double[]. A solution would be to cast all elements to Integer/Double, but I wonder if I can solve this issue more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic method

```
public static <T> void writeArrayToTxt(T[] array, String filename)
```

and use it different types of arrays

```
Integer[] intArr = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3};
Double[] doubleArr = new Double[] {4.5, 5.3, 3.2};
String[] stringArr = new String[] {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
writeArrayToTxt(intArr, "somefile1");
writeArrayToTxt(doubleArr, "somefile2");
writeArrayToTxt(stringArr, "somefile3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature to:

```
public static void writeArrayToTxt(Number[] array, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
```

and call it like that:

```
Integer[] arrayInt = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
writeArrayToTxt(arrayInt, "test.txt");
```